# Copy unsigned short with memcpy

Tags: struct, memcpy

I have a *'**runtime error**'* when I try to copy the value of the variable 'b' into the variable 'a'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
        unsigned short a;
}st1;

main()
{
        st1* myStruct;
        unsigned short b = 0xFFFF;

        memcpy(&myStruct->a, &b,sizeof(b));
}
```

I would like to know why it happens.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that using `memcpy()` to copy an `unsigned short` is taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.  Writing `myStruct->a = b;` would do the same job (only quicker and clearer), and would create the same havoc while `myStruct` is an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did not allocate memory for `myStruct`. You didn't initialize it, so its value is some random value during `memcpy()`. Thus, `&myStruct->a` is accessing some random address, and writing to `&myStruct->a` is likely to lead to runtime error.

Comment: You are right.

I have to add the following line:

myStruct = (st1*) malloc (sizeof(st1));

Thank you very much!